# how to use modulo function to determine if the given year is a leap yaer or not in vi editor of linux

Tags: windows-xp

I am not able to run a program  in vi-editor of Linux which is to determine whether the entered year is a leap year or not so I require necessary directions in order to execute my program. thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order to run a Program from vi editor, you need to type following command in vi editor after saving your file.

type: `:!gcc -o anyname % && ./anyname`

Here `%` refer to current file. It will use gcc to compile your program and execute it.